# Deleting values in one column corresponding to another using Python

Tags: python

I save the data in a csv file in two columns, `T` and `L1`. Then I remove some values from `L1` using `L2` and generate a new list, `L3`. Now I would like to save the values of `T` corresponding to `L3`. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import csv 
T=[1,2,3,4,5]
L1=[(0, 0), (0, 7), (3, 2), (7, 9), (7, 0)]
L2=[(0, 0), (0, 7), (3, 2)]
L3 = [i for i in L1 if i not in L2]
#print(L3)
header1 = ['T','Indices']
with open('Indices1234.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header1)

    # write the data
    writer.writerows(zip(T,L1))    


header2 = ['T','Indices']
with open('Indices123.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header2)

    # write the data
    writer.writerows(zip(T,L3))
```

Current output:

[image: Current output]

Desired output

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper list, T3, which contains elements from T that you want to add to your second csv file.
Code:

```
T=[1,2,3,4,5]
L1=[(0, 0), (0, 7), (3, 2), (7, 9), (7, 0)]
L2=[(0, 0), (0, 7), (3, 2)]
L3 = [i for i in L1 if i not in L2]
T3 = [T[L1.index(i)] for i in L1 if i not in L2]
print(T3)
print(L3)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5]
[(7, 9), (7, 0)]
```

What this code does is maybe difficult to understand from a list comprehension. So I've written an expanded version:

```
# 1.) find elements which are in L1 but not in L2:
elements = [i for i in L1 if i not in L2]

# 2.) now get indices of those elements
indices = [L1.index(i) for i in elements]

# 3.) get elements from T
T3 = [T[index] for index in indices]
print(T3)
```

The output is the same as above.
Basically the list `elements` contains elements which are in L1 but not in L2 (note: this can be done using sets as well).

After that, instead of the actual values of the elements, we get their indices. That is list `indices`.

The final step is to get the elements from `T`, at the appropriate index.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close with the list comprehension.

One soltion is to get the lists of the same length which would make the problem trivial, you can change the list comprehension to this:

```py
L3 = [i in L1 if i in L2 else False for i in L1]
```

which will return this:

```
[True, True, True, False, False]
```

From this point it is easy to assign `T` as you have an equal length list with `True` or `False`.

For example you can iterate through the list do (write) only the lines that you wish to:

```py
for i in L3:
    if i == False:
        print('write to the CSV')
    else:
        print('no need to write anything')
```

In fact i might even recomment a dataframe for clarity (which is beyond the scope of the question, but potentially helpful).

The rest is left to you...

Comment: How to assign ```T``` from here? Can you tell more about the dataframe?

Comment: in simple, the lists lend themselves quite nicely to a `pandas dataframe` if they are the same length. You can get them the same length by *padding* `L2`. With regards to assigning `T` it depends how (which is why i left that part open)...  do you want a `dict` or `list` for example ?   probably worth opening a second question...

Comment: I want a list for ```T```.

Comment: I dont know the contents of the CSV, but `pandas` also has a convenient method for both reading and writing CSV (directly into and from a dataframe) which will probably save you extra work...

Comment: If I have to solve the above problem using ```pandas```, how do I do it? May be there are some resources which can help?

Comment: You dont have to, but it would certainly be convenient given that you are dealing with reading and writing CSV data...